# Take each character from a string and assign it to a new string

Tags: python, string, split

The titles probably a little confusing, so sorry. Let's say

```
String = "hello"
```

And I need it to create a number of strings depending on how many characters there are. In this case 5. Then each character would be assigned to a new string. Like this:

```
Str1 = "h"
Str2 = "e"
Str3 = "l"
Str4 = "l"
Str5 = "o"
```

In the past I've done something similar with:

```
Str1, Str2, Str3, Str4, Str5 = String.split(' ')
```

But this splits the string every word not every character and I want the strings to be created depending on the number of characters.

Comment: can you store all the new strings in a list? `lst = list(String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
st = "hello"
c_arr = [c for c in st]
```

this will return an array with every char as an element ,,

note that you can apply any function to this character in the list like this

```
c_arr = [c + "1" for c in st]
```

this will result in ["h1","e1","l1","l1","o1"]

**update : **
how to access arrays

```
print(c_arr[2])
```

this will print the 3rd element ,, note that it's a zero-indexed list ,,
read more about lists in python here : 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: This might work but how would I go about getting characters out of this array? For example how would I get the second character out? Sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to see how many characters are in the original string?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? I'm assuming you just want to edit each individual character of the string, but python wont allow you. You could do this:

```
string = "hello"
string = list(string)
```

Then edit each individual character like string[1] = "b"
And when your done to make it back into a string:

```
''.join(string)
```

Comment: I am doing this for an encryption program that encrypts each individual character based on an algorithm. So I don't think this will work. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it.  A string is its own iterator:

```
Str1, Str2, Str3, Str4, Str5 = String
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you just want to access the characters of a string. To do that, you can just subscript `String` directly. For example for

```
String = "hello"
```

you can access the second character with

```
secondChar = String[1]
```

This will assign `"e"` to `secondChar`.